# Spark sql registered temp table cannot be used in sqlContext.read()?

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code

```
Map<String, String> props = getDbConnectionProps();
        props.put("dbtable", sql);
        props.put("fetchSize", "100000");
        props.put("partitionColumn", "col1");
        props.put("lowerBound", "25");
        props.put("upperBound", "100");
        props.put("numPartitions", "10");
String sql = "..."
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(props).load();
df.registerTempTable("myTable");
df.cache();

Map<String, String> props = getDbConnectionProps();
        props.put("dbtable", sql2);
        props.put("fetchSize", "100000");
        props.put("partitionColumn", "col1");
        props.put("lowerBound", "25");
        props.put("upperBound", "100");
        props.put("numPartitions", "10");
String sql2 = "... inner join myTable on ...."   // Note here the sql2 use the temp table
DataFrame df2 = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(props).load();
```

However, I got an error below

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'myDbSchema.myTable' doesn't exist
```

So the registered temp table cannot be used in sqlContext.read()? I understand I can use `sqlContext.sql(sql2)` to get the result using temp table. However, how can I set those properties  such as partition information in the sqlContext.sql() way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clearly evident that you are reading from Database using `.format("jdbc")`, while `df.registerTempTable("myTable");` is an spark entity/data present in memory after loading data.

```
DataFrame df2 = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(props).load();
```

And error states that myDbSchema.myTable doesn't exist, because the query string which you have passed is operating on Database.

```
sql2 = "... inner join myTable on ...."
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'myDbSchema.myTable' doesn't exist
```

For your Question: I understand I can use sqlContext.sql(sql2) to get the result using temp table. However, how can I set those properties such as partition information in the sqlContext.sql() way?

Solution 1 is optimal when two datasets are too huge to be joined/handled by database and vice versa. please find below pseudo code.

**Solution 1:** Load data of 2nd table in DF2 then perform join in spark.

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(props).load();
DataFrame df2 = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(props2).load();
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",10)
DataFrame joindf = df.join(df2, joinCondition, "inner")
```

**Solution 2:** Create a view/table in database by joining two tables, for example `joinedview` here, and load data through read parallelism => Partitions into spark.

```
In Database:
create view joinedview as 
select * from table inner join myTable 
on (joincondition)

In Spark:
Map<String, String> props = getDbConnectionProps();
        props.put("dbtable", joinedview);
        props.put("fetchSize", "100000");
        props.put("partitionColumn", "col1");
        props.put("lowerBound", "25");
        props.put("upperBound", "100");
        props.put("numPartitions", "10");
DataFrame df2 = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc").options(props).load();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do it without sql, but I think the error may be showing up since you are trying to read the table "myTable" with format("jdbc") instead of from however your temporary storage is setup.